# Implement properties in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class `MyVisible` having a property *`Visible`*.

I have a class `MySuperVisible` implementing a interface `ISuperVisible`, that contains also property *`Visible`*.

How should I implement the "Visible" property of the interface "ISuperVisible" in "MySuperVisible" class?

```
Class MySuperVisible
  Inherits MyVisible
  Implements ISuperVisible

... 

Private Property PrivatePropertyPlaceholder Implements ISuperVisible.Visible
  Get
    Return MyBase.Visible
  End Get
  Set
    MyBase.Visible = value
  End Set
End Property
```

is implementing a private property the only solution to do it?

PS. 
MySuperVisible inherits MyVisible, so I need to implement a property that already exists in the base class.

Comment: Why do you want to implement a private property? And what is `MyBase.Visible`? I think you haven't given us all info. Could it be that `MySuperVisible` inherits from `MyVisible` AND implements `ISuperVisible`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `Visible` property from `MyVisible` is in conflict with the need to implement the `Visible` from `ISuperVisible`. Is that right? If so, I believe Mike C is right: If I'm not mistaken, `Shadows` should force the implementation in `MySuperVisible` to override that from `MyVisible`.

Comment: Yes, thanks to Mike C to completing the question. MySuperVisible inherits MyVisible, so I need to implement a property that already exists in the base class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I think the `Shadows` keyword is probably the appropriate way to go here.  That makes things a little more explicit than `PrivatePropertyPlaceholder`:

```
Public Shadows Property Visible As Boolean Implements ISuperVisible.Visible
    Get
        Return MyBase.Visible
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        MyBase.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: what about just the line `Public Shadows Property Visible As Boolean Implements ISuperVisible.Visible`? need I write all the body explicitly?

Comment: If you shadow it without the property body and its explicit set/get from/to mybase, the base class visible property will not be set.